# Swift class with uibutton.addTarget to UIView not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton, addtarget

I created a new file with the following class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

var Feld = classFeld()

class classFeld {

     let button = UIButton()

     func createButton() -> UIButton {
         button.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 200, height: 100)
         button.backgroundColor=UIColor.black
         button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ButtonPressed(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }

    @objc func ButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
        button.backgroundColor=UIColor.red
    }
}
```

And this is my ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainview.addSubview(Feld.createButton())
        self.view.addSubview(mainview)
    }

    var  mainview=UIView()
}
```

When I start the app a black button is created but when I click on it it doesnt color red.
If I add the button instead of

```
mainview.addSubview(Feld.createButton())
```

to

```
self.view.addSubview(Feld.createButton())
```

it works and the button turns red.

May I anyone explain me why? It should make no difference if I add something to self.view or to a subview which is then added to self.view?

Comment: How you are setting frames for mainview ?

Comment: I didnt set at all. It works with setting it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you need to give it a frame and add it to `self.view`

```
var mainview = UIView()
```

Comment: Adding a frame works! Thanks a lot. I dont understand though why the button is displayed (black) without a frame. And addTarget (turning red) is not displayed without a frame.

Comment: This always happens with frames , actually the mainView had a zero default frame , but if you set **mainview.clipsToBounds = true** the button won't show

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are just initializing a `UIView` without giving it any frame and adding it to the main view.

You need to give frame to your mainview also. For example :

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
   var mainview = UIView()
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainview.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 300, height: 300)
        self.view.addSubview(mainview)
        mainview.addSubview(Feld.createButton())
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is changes on `ViewController` class and working fine:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var  mainview: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        mainview = UIView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        mainview.addSubview(Feld.createButton())
        self.view.addSubview(mainview)

    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is at mainView frame